# How to get set of dates in a specific week ,given the month and the year?

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

How to get The `dates` in a specific week given the month and the year ?

For example:

My parameters :

```
June - 2013  - The second week
```

---

I want the result set like this :

```
9-6-2013
10-6-2013
11-6-2013
12-6-2013
13-6-2013
```

---

**I want it starting from Sun to Thu .**

Comment: How are you defining "week"? Always starting with the 8th? Always starting with Saturday? Week-of-week-year in ISO terms?

Comment: i want it start from Sunday to Wednesday , in my example it's the second week

Comment: So what exactly is the problem you have with writing code? Figuring out what day of the week is any particular day? Finding first day of the given month? Incrementing days till you find first day that satisfy your criteria? Counting to 7?

Comment: I write  method , but i think it 's specific to my case , i want some general way

Comment: You say you want Sun to Wed but your example shows Sun to Thu?

Comment: Sorry u are right it should be to Thu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well in my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) library I would:

- Start from the end of the previous month
- Loop as many times as you want finding the next Sunday
- Go from there, yielding the days (so you can just use a `foreach` loop):

So:

```
IEnumerable<LocalDate> GetSundayToWednesday(int year, int month, int week)
{
    LocalDate date = new LocalDate(year, month, 1).PlusDays(-1);        
    for (int i = 0; i < week; i++)
    {
        date = date.Next(IsoDayOfWeek.Sunday);
    }
    // You always want 4 days, Sunday to Wednesday
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        yield return date;
        date = date.PlusDays(1);
    }
}
```

Using just `DateTime`, I'd probably start at the first day of the month that it *could* be (week * 7 + 1) and loop until I hit the right day of week, then go from there:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> GetSundayToWednesday(int year, int month, int week)
{
    // Consider breaking this part out into a separate method?
    DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, week * 7 + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            break;
        }
        date = date.AddDays(1);
    }
    // You always want 4 days, Sunday to Wednesday
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        yield return date;
        date = date.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

Looping like this isn't terribly efficient - you could just work out how many days to advance - but it's more obviously *right*. You can very easily end up with off-by-one errors (or going back into the previous month) with a more efficient approach. You may choose to put more effort into being efficient if this is important, of course.

Comment: I was just about to say that Mr. StackOverflow works on Noda Time and he would recommend it!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have not really tested this but I think that does more or less what you want:

```
        int year = 2013;
        int month = 6;
        int lookupWeek = 2;

        int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
        int weekCounter = 1;

        List<DateTime> weekDays = new List<DateTime>();

        for (int day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++)
        {
            DateTime date = new DateTime(year,month,day);
            if(date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday && day > 1) weekCounter++;

            if(weekCounter == lookupWeek) weekDays.Add(date);
        }
```

Comment: Updated it a few times with more clear variable names and a fix with the week numbering.

Answer (score 1):

This method gives the days in a specific week of a month:

```
static IEnumerable<string> DaysInWeek(int year, int month, int week)
{
    var date = new DateTime(year, month, 1);

    var calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    var firstWeek = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
    var days = calendar.GetDaysInMonth(year, month);

    var daysInWeek = (from day in Enumerable.Range(0, calendar.GetDaysInMonth(year, month) - 1)
                        let dayDate = date.AddDays(day)
                        let week2 = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dayDate, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, DayOfWeek.Sunday) - firstWeek + 1
                        where week2 == week
                        select day + 1).ToList();

    foreach (var d in daysInWeek) yield return string.Format("{0:00}-{1:00}-{2:0000}", d, month, year);
}
```

And the output of this:

```
foreach (var d in DaysInWeek(week, year, month).Take(5)) Log.Info(d);
```

Would be:

```
09-06-2013
10-06-2013
11-06-2013
12-06-2013
13-06-2013
```

Note: I have edited the code. There was a little bug; because in many months, first week and last week are not complete weeks and some days of that week belongs to another month.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the client-side (JavaScript) route, then [date.js](http://www.datejs.com) might be worth a look, it allows for the following:

```
// What date is next thursday?
Date.today().next().thursday();

// Add 3 days to Today
Date.today().add(3).days();

// Is today Friday?
Date.today().is().friday();

// Number fun
(3).days().ago();

// 6 months from now
var n = 6;
n.months().fromNow();

// Set to 8:30 AM on the 15th day of the month
Date.today().set({ day: 15, hour: 8, minute: 30 });

// Convert text into Date
Date.parse('today');
Date.parse('t + 5 d'); // today + 5 days
Date.parse('next thursday');
Date.parse('February 20th 1973');
Date.parse('Thu, 1 July 2004 22:30:00');
```

I find the natural language syntax (i.e. 'next thursday') to be quite powerful.

Answer (score 1):

If you were keen to use linq (I almost always am!), you could do this:

```
int year = 2013;
int month = 6;
int weekOfMonth = 2;

var dates = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))
                    .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day))
                    .GroupBy(g=> g.DayOfYear/7)
                    .ToList();

var week = dates.Min(g => g.Key) + weekOfMonth - 1;
var result = dates.Where(g=> g.Key.Equals(week)).Select(g => g.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
protected void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 6, 1);
        string[] dates = getDates(dt);

   }
        public string[] getDates(DateTime dt)
    {
        string[] result = new string[7]; ;
        for (int i = getDay(dt.DayOfWeek.ToString()); i < 7; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                dt = dt.AddDays(1);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            dt = dt.AddDays(1);
            result[i] = dt.ToShortDateString();
        }
        return result;
    }
    public int getDay(string day)
    {
        switch (day)
        {
            case "Monday":
                return 0;
            case "Tuesday":
                return 1;
            case "Wednesday":
                return 2;
            case "Thursday":
                return 3;
            case "Friday":
                return 4;
            case "Saturday":
                return 5;
            case "Sunday":
                return 6;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }## Heading ##
```

Comment: -1: "try this" without **any** comments is not a good format for answers on SO.